# Child div 1 overflows Parent div and I can't get Child div 2 (child div 1s sibling) to be same width as child div 1

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a codesandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-ioana-vxbuv2?file=/src/App.js:1135-1144) that shows what I mean. I want the blue table to be as wide as the width of all the cards. The cardsData length will vary, and don't want to add complexity by calculating its width. is there a way for parent's width (or sibling width) to become the same as overflowing cards width?

Thanks in advance. If it's easier, here's the same code pasted

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

import {
  Box,
  Grid,
  TableContainer,
  Paper,
  Table,
  TableHead,
  TableRow,
  TableCell
} from "@mui/material";
export default function App() {
  const cardsData = [{}, {}, {}, {}, {}];

  const TableData = () => (
    <TableContainer
      component={Paper}
      sx={{ width: "100%", background: "blue" }}
    >
      <Table id='would like table to extand same width as width of cards' sx={{ ".MuiTableCell-root": { minWidth: "20%" } }}>
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell></TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
      </Table>
    </TableContainer>
  );

  const Cards = ({ i }) => (
    <Box
      sx={{
        background: i === 0 ? "#f6f7f7" : "#f5f7fe",
        minWidth: "20%",
        maxWidth: "250px",
        borderRadius: "4px",
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "column",
        gap: 3,
        pt: 0,
        pb: 4,
        pl: 4,
        pr: 4
      }}
    />
  );

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Box
        sx={{
          display: "flex",
          gap: "16px",
          minHeight: "250px"
        }}
      >
        {cardsData?.map((c, i) => (
          <Cards cardData={c} i={i} key={i} />
        ))}
        {/* extra card just cuz */}
        <Cards />
      </Box>
      <TableData />
    </div>
  );
}
```